# How to dynamically change cloth constraints in code? Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, so I have a capsule that when it collides with the cloth I want the cloth to stick to the capsule, I can select the constraints and replace them with new values. what I'm having trouble with is getting the constraints that the capsule is nearest to on the cloth when it collides with the cloth. I'm thinking it has something to do with the contact points of the capsule collider?

basically, I'm trying to make "tape". I can collide with the cloth but when I move the capsule back up I need the cloth to stick to it.

[Video of what I have so far](https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/420B150n1k1X3g1l2V2P/Screen%20Recording%202018-01-13%20at%2006.55.43%20PM.mp4)

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) 
{
    Rigidbody colRb = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    colRb.isKinematic = true;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Vector3 contactPoint = col.contacts[0].point; //the location of where the collision is on the col 

    for (int i = 0; i < newConstraints.Length; i++)
    {
        if(contactPoint == tape.vertices[i])
        {
            //I need to only select the indices that are near the contactPoint, not all of them as in this case with i
            newConstraints[i].maxDistance = 0;
            tape.coefficients = newConstraints;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Although it would likely be slow, you could test for collision and intersection of every vertice in the colliding object.

Comment: I added an if statement to compare the two vector3's but it still doesn't work

Comment: How are you storing your faces? Do you have some sort of Triangle or Face struct? test for an intersection within each face with each vertex of the colliding model.

Comment: I can get the vertice locations of the skinned mesh of the cloth, I can get the contact point location on collision but I'm not sure how to translate that into getting the index of the newConstraints array